# How can I print Error Message in my console when I enter wrong data in the date field

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here is my code,

```
WebElement Dob=driver.findElement(By.id("DateOfBirth"));
Dob.clear();
Dob.sendKeys("10052011");
Dob.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
Thread.sleep(50);
try{
    boolean doberr=driver.findElement(By.id("DateOfBirth-error")).isDisplayed();
    if(doberr==true){
        System.out.println("Date of Birth must be less than or equal to MemberCommencingDate");
    }
    }catch(Exception e10){
    //don't stop my script
    e10.printStackTrace();
}
//Gender
Select Gender=new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("Gender")));
Gender.selectByIndex(1);
```

When I give an invalid date in DateOfBirth field, WebDriver prints the message on console but when I set a valid input script, the test fails and the driver is not able to select the gender.

Comment: what's the html where it fails? exception or error thrown would be useful to post here

Comment: Your question headline is "How can i print Error Message in my console..." and then you wrote "webdriver printed the message in console", so what is actually your problem? Whether `Gender` is found or not has probably nothing to do with your input in `DateOfBirth`. Please explain in more detail what the script does and how it fails.

Comment: in my try catch block when the condition is true, script getting executed but  when the condition is false means the webdriver struck at Gender field and no further execution observed